# Issue with background img disappearing when the browser is a certain width

Tags: html, css

So I have an issue when the screen is a certain width my background photo disappears. It's weird because at full screen (desktop) it's fine and on mobile it's fine. It's kinda the in-between space like tablets or small desktop screens where the background photo leaves/disappears. (The site was written with "responsiveness" in mind.)

The code is quite extensive so it would probably be easier to visit the page in question and use "inspect" to see the code. Unfortunately, iv tried some solutions but they have not worked which means I have no clue what I am doing wrong! How can I get the photo to NOT disappear regardless of the browser/screen width?

See the page @ Zoeaa.com

RECREATE ISSUE BY: Reducing the browser and at a certain point, and the background photo should disappear.

Would really appreciate the help! If there is anything I can do to improve this question, please let me know!

[Photo of site working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32SOB.png)
[Photo of the site not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhfOh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your site and I think this is not actually background issue but height issue on the element which you applied this background image.

I found something like that:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1360px){
     .px_slider, .px_slider .slides>li {
          height: auto !important;
     }
 }
```

So when `height: auto !important;` the element I found `height` is `0` that's why background image not showing. **So just check you media query break-points wheres you wrote same type of CSS.**

See here:

[image]

And when showing:

[image]

Comment: I think I understood but could you clarify a little further. Also, did you see the code appear when in desktop, mobile or at another screen dimension?

Comment: Just check In which view background going off those view may element height is zero that's why it is not showing. Such as I found in @media only screen and (max-width: 1360px) ".px_slider, .px_slider .slides>li" is zero.